# Upload document pdf type in CodeIgniter not accepting filename containing numbers

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

This are the configuration setting for my upload functionality in codeigniter.

```
$config['upload_path']   = '_resources/temp/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|pdf';
$config['overwrite']     = true; # Overwrite the existing file
$config['max_width']     = '1024';
$config['max_height']    = '768';
$config['max_size']      = '0'; # No limit

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

and this is the function use to upload file in pdf type.

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('myfile')) {
    $result = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>'));
} else {
    $result['names']        = directory_map('_resources/temp/'); # Get file stored in this directory
    $result['remove_url']   = site_url('transaction_items/remove_file');
    $result['temp_url']     = site_url('_resources/temp');
    $result['get_file_url'] = site_url('transaction_items/get_temp_file');
    $result['is_okay']      = 'true';
}
echo json_encode( $result );
```

The problem when I tried to upload document that is pdf type having a filename `2016` for example, CodeIgniter return this result.

```
$result = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>'));
```

Does anyone know, how to allow uploading document having filename containing numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Everytime I upload pdf file with numeric filename , codeigniter will say filetype is not supported even though it must be supported given the it accept alpha-numeric filename.

Comment: i dont think so it is due to numeric filename. check with your file type. Which version of Codeigniter you are using?

Comment: Updated. We have they same thinking, but I wonder why.